# Inserting multiple rows into html table ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a query that selects rows according to a certain defined criteria. Once that happens I have a reader that gets the values for use. My problem is how can I get a variable amount of rows the reader returned to my ASP.Net behind code page? Also be able to get the individual rows and not just the first row. I am not sure if a counter needs to be set or honestly what to do. How can I get these variable amounts of rows into the appropriate labels? If you want to see any code let me know.

DBHelper class where:

```
private DBHelper() { }

    public static SqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    }

    public static SqlConnection getFRESHConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FRESHConnection"].ConnectionString);
    }

    public static SqlDataReader executeQuery(SqlConnection dbConn, string sqlString, SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            if (dbConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                dbConn.Open();
            cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sqlString;
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            }
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return reader;
    }
```

DataClass:

```
public class LineAData
{
    public int CaseNum6;
    public int CaseNum9;
    public int Group;
    public bool Completed;
    public int WorkID;


    public void load(int Group1, int Group2)
    {
        StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
        sqlString.Append("SELECT WorkID, CaseNum6, CaseNum9, Group, Completed ");
        sqlString.Append("FROM WorkOrder ");
        sqlString.Append("WHERE Group = @Group1 OR Group = @Group2 ");
        sqlString.Append("AND Completed =  '0' ");

        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        SqlConnection dbConn = DBHelper.getConnection();

        SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@Group1", Group1 ), 
                                                         new SqlParameter("@Group2", Group2) };

        try
        {
            reader = DBHelper.executeQuery(dbConn, sqlString.ToString(), parameters);
            if (reader != null)
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    WorkID = (int)(reader["WorkID"]);
                    CaseNum6 = (int)(reader["CaseNum6"]);
                    CaseNum9 = (int)(reader["CaseNum9"]);
                    Group = (int)(reader["Group"]);
                    Completed = (bool)reader["Completed"];
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("No record returned");
                reader.Close();
                reader.Dispose();
                dbConn.Close();
                dbConn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dbConn != null)
            {
                try { dbConn.Close(); dbConn.Dispose(); }
                catch { }
            }
            if (reader != null)
            {
                try { reader.Close(); reader.Dispose(); }
                catch { }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes its better to provide the code !!

Comment: We're programmers, we ALWAYS want to see code. :)

Comment: Have you tried the Datagrid control ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @huMptyduMpty code update

Comment: @paqogomez code update

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos: why `(int)Convert.ToInt32`?? always do `reader["WorkID"]!=dbnull.value?Convert.ToInt32(reader["WorkID"]):0;`

Comment: @huMptyduMpty that is a great question actually didn't realize that. also not getting that last part.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos: Do you have a table created on your frontend you do you just need to display the data using grid or something?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Yes I have a html table with labels centered and the data will need to  be passed to those labels to be displayed. I can do that part it's just getting the rows in I can't seem to get in ASP.

Comment: survey says:  "Make a loop"!

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that stores the following fields:

```
 public class Class1
{
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public int CaseNum6 { get; set; }
    public int CaseNum9 { get; set; }
    public int Group { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}
```

Then instead of using   `if (reader.Read())`
Use while(reader.read())

```
List<Class1> myList = new List<Class1>();
while(reader.read())
{
   // assign the reader values to your class
   myClass obj = new myClass();
   obj.WorkId= reader["WorkId"]
   obj.CaseNum6 = reader["CaseNum6"]
   // do for all fields

   // add to the list
   myList.Add(obj)
}
```

Now you have a variable number of results stored in "myList"!

Of course, remember to close your reader or wrap it in a using statement.

Comment: Oh, the text was copied in wrong there and is misleading.  only call it once.

Comment: I just realized I need to re-run the query in that class to make the reader work.